# Assumption is the mother of all fuck-ups... in Russian (sorry:)

Tags: значения

Is there an equivalent expression in Russian (not a direct translation) of

"Assumption is the mother of all fuck-ups" quote?

Comment: I can't think of a clever idiom with the same meaning. I would simply say: *Предположение - мать всех ошибок*

Comment: @Vilmar "предположение" is so vague here that the meaning is lost.

Comment: "Assumption" seems a little vague too. What the idiom usually stands for?

Comment: Nothing vague in original or translation - it means that quite often making an assumption instead of relying on facts leads to, well, fuck-ups :) E.g.: You are an owner of a jewelry store. A man in a dirty shirt and shorts comes in. You assume based on his appearance that he is simply window-shopping and you are reluctant to offer any help. The man goes into a nearby store and buys 100.000$ worth of jewelry for his wife. He was a rich guy coming home from a football match, and your assumption just cost you 100k.

Comment: @Vilmar The meaning is clear, but the preferred usage not. For your example, I'd say, probably, "Встречают по одёжке, провожают по кошельку" ;-)

Comment: @user4419802, yeah that was just an example that fits the idiom you provided :)

Answer (score 5):

Some variants on the subject (not sure which suits better):

> Наперёд не загадывай
>
> Наперёд не узнаешь, где найдёшь, где потеряешь
>
> Человек предполагает, а Бог - располагает

or even

> Гладко было на бумаге, да забыли про овраги

Comment: Last one is the best, I think, and should be the first.

Comment: We have an equivalent phrase "Man proposes, God disposes" and it has a different meaning. The poster's original question basically means that when you assume something, you risk fucking up somehow... not the same thing.

Comment: @CocoPop Well, actually all mentioned proverbs have somewhat different meanings.

Comment: I see. I'm not too clear on the meaning of  пиздец, but can it also mean a fuck-up? in other words a bad situation that resulted from an error?

Comment: @CocoPop It's an obscene word, so it can have different meanings including the opposite ones, much like "fuck" in English. But yes, usually that means "a really bad situation". It has no reference to "an error", though AFAIK "fuck-up" has neither too. But I'm in doubt whether "fuck-up" should be translated as "пиздец", because the latter seems to be much stronger. Also, sometimes people change it to "песец" ("polar fox") (or even the descriptive "белый пушной зверёк" - "white fur animal").

Answer (score 4):

A common Russian response to *я думал...* ("I thought that...") is *индюк тоже думал, да в суп попал* ("A gobbler was a thinker too but ended up in a dish of stew")

Comment: Quite close, though it can be used only post-factum, I guess (and as a response only, that restricts the usage as well).

Comment: what's a gobbler?

Comment: @CocoPop: a male turkey (*индюк*).